# NAV Web Service how to update data via C#?

Tags: c#, web-services, web-reference, navision

so bear with me if I'm doing anything wrong.
i have been trying to update some data in Nav from C#, but whatever i do i get errors:

my code Unit looks like this, this is my method i need to use to update:

```
<operation name="OpdaterVogn">
    <operation soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/BMG:OpdaterVogn"style="document"/>
  <input name="OpdaterVogn">
    <body use="literal"/>
  </input>
  <output name="OpdaterVogn_Result">
    <body use="literal"/>
  </output>
</operation>
```

ill show u my objects i get passed via my codeunit aswell:

```
<schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x78001">
  <complexType name="VognType">
    <sequence>
      <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Kode" type="string"/>
      <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="RegNr" type="string"/>
      <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Beskrivelse" type="string"/>
      <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" default="false" name="Spaerret" type="boolean"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
  <complexType name="Vogn" mixed="true">
    <sequence>
      <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Vogn" type="tns:VognType"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
  <element name="Vogn" type="tns:Vogn"/>
</schema>
```

anyway, moving on to C#, i can get the data over to C# and review it. Now i want to update a "vogn" with the method.

at the moment my code looks like this:

```
        BMGWS ws = new BMGWS();
        Vogn vogne = new Vogn();
        VognType vogn = new VognType();
        ws.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        ws.SendVogn("BMG 2013", false, ref vogne);

        vogn = vogne.Vogn1[0];
        string kode = vogn.Kode;
        string beskrivelse = vogn.Beskrivelse;
        string regnr = vogn.RegNr;
        bool spaerret = vogn.Spaerret;

        Vogn vogneNy = new Vogn();
        VognType vognNy = new VognType();
        vognNy.Kode = kode; // string value to update
        vognNy.Beskrivelse = beskrivelse; // string value to update
        vognNy.RegNr = regnr; // string value to update 
        vognNy.Spaerret = spaerret; // Bool value to update 

        List<VognType> list = new List<VognType>();
        list.Add(vognNy);
        vogneNy.Vogn1 = list.ToArray();
        vogneNy.Vogn1[0] = vognNy;


        ws.OpdaterVogn("BMG 2013", vogneNy);
```

my last method wont work, i get the following error:

{"The Element `<Kode>` is expected by Min Occurs value: Once. Element received: `<>`."}

hopefully you guys can help me in here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you're using Codeunits with XmlPorts in Nav. You should follow the below link and scroll down to the bit about MinOccurs and MaxOccurs, needs to be specified in the XMLPort in Nav specifically:

http://www.kauffmann.nl/blog/index.php/2011/02/24/how-to-use-xmlports-in-web-services-2/